# How to know which row and which section is editing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 10 sections and each section has only 1 row. Row contain 5  text fields.
if I change any text field value how to update to particular row ?

It should not effect to another sections rows. I have taken customview for cell designing.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [https://stackoverflow.com/a/2...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27877341/3177007) answer. Set the tag for textfield and use Dictionary to store values, Otherwise the reusing cell the textfield text re-appearing in other cells.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` return section and row... Do your own logic in Dict to store textfield values...

```
[txtfield addTarget:self  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)txtField
 {
 UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[txtField.superview viewWithTag:100];
 NSString *labelString = label.text;
 NSString *textFieldString = txtField.text;
 [amounts setObject:textFieldString forKey:labelString];
 }
```

Maintain unique key for cell or textfield to store in dict, check the dict for key exist, if exist change the value else add new key with value.

I think this is, what you want...Do your best...